# asp.net mvc + detect hashtag change

Tags: jquery, url, hashtag, asp.net-core-1.1

When I try to detect hashtag change in url, for example:

`http://localhost:54345/Shop/Catalog?cg=9#3221`

to

`http://localhost:54345/Shop/Product#1241`

Jquery hashchange method does not fire.

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function (e) {
    //....
})
```

If the hashtag changes between Catalog action, then it detects. Ex:

`http://localhost:54345/Shop/Catalog?cg=9#3221`

`http://localhost:54345/Shop/Catalog?cg=9#2453`

So my question is, hashtag detection is not possible between different requests? or different ASP.NET MVC Actions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**`hashchange()`**](https://api.jquerymobile.com/hashchange/) only works on hashtag changes to the same **page**.

Depending when you want the event to fire, you can target the [**`unload()`**](http://api.jquery.com/unload/) of the first page:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
  // do something before the page unloads
});
```

Or the [**`load()`**](http://api.jquery.com/load/) of the new page, which would be done simply with **[`ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)**:

```
$(window).ready(function() {
  // do something after the new page loads
});
```

If going with the latter, you can add **conditional** logic that checks against the hashtag to simulate the same effect:

```
if(window.location.hash) {
  // Fragment exists
}
```

Hope this helps! :)